# Jquery - stop script executing on if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop script executing when if condition is met? Is it possible to do it without else? For example:

```
if(data == 'false')
{
stop
}
rest of the function...
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can return out of the function:

```
if (data == 'false') {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Who could guess that there was an easy solution :D. Thank you for your help :).